# Can I develop applications for the Ubuntu Software Center using KDE?

Tags: application-development, kde

I am interested in making an application to sell in the Ubuntu Software Center. Can I do this using the KDE frameworks and C++ or any other KDE-compatible language instead of Gtk and Python? I am not interested in making a KDE/Kubuntu-specific application, just an application to be used on Ubuntu/Kubuntu written using the KDE frameworks.

If this is allowed, is there any major reason why I should choose Gtk and Python over KDE and C++?

Comment: Well, you can install KDE-Apps from the Software Center, so my answer is yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes you can

Ubuntu supports variety of programming languages and toolkits. You can use any of them for your app .But qml ang Ubuntu tool kit is officially recommended

Comment: I understand that Ubuntu supports a variety of programming languages and toolkits and will allow KDE apps to be run and developed on Ubuntu, but will a KDE application be able to meet the requirements for submission to Software Center?

Comment: Yes,it will meet the requirement, GTK is recommendation only