# Should I choose KDE or Qt for an Ubuntu application?

Tags: application-development, kde, qt

I'm writing an application using QML and some C++ code. The main window will be all QML (possibly having a main menu bar provided `KXmlGuiWindow`), with the backend and some dialogs written in C++. I've been using KDE because I'm using the KDE desktop and I like some of the extra features KDE provides, like KConfig XT. However, I'm planning on selling my application in the Ubuntu Software Center, so I assume my main target will be the standard Ubuntu with Unity. Knowing this, should I limit myself to using just Qt or is using the KDE frameworks not something to worry about?

I've asked a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/271663/109543), and I understand KDE applications are allowed, but is there a good enough reason to choose pure Qt and not use the extra features KDE provides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choosing pure Qt/QML will make it easier to also sell your application on the Phone and Tablet versions of Ubuntu, once the software store is available on Ubuntu Touch, as the KDE libs will not necessarily be available or usable, on those devices.

Choosing to use KDE frameworks may make some things easier when developing, but will also result in a lot more dependencies being pulled in by your package, many of which may be wholly unnecessary for the most part.

Deciding what to use is up to you. You'll have to decide where you want to compromise, and what the target market you want to sell your app to, is.

Comment: I was considering whether I might sell it on the Phablet version. But for the desktop, will using KDE draw people away from buying it under Ubuntu?

Comment: When selling in the Software Center, will my target audience mostly be Ubuntu, or do people use Software Center under Kubuntu & KDE also?

Comment: Software Center is available, and used, on some derivatives of Ubuntu, and some ship their own version of it, though I don't know if Muon (which I think Kubuntu uses by default) supports purchasing of software. Using KDE (or any other APIs really) may be cause for some people not purchasing it, yes. Typically only advanced technical users will give concern to it though. So again, it's a matter of understanding your target market, and making appropriate compromises for them, and what you need to develop.

Comment: What about startup time? Will an application that uses KDE take longer (rather, long enough to notice) to load because it has to load all the KDE libraries?

Comment: It depends on what libraries you use, and how you design/write your app, but it is a possibility, yes. Ask Ubuntu is not a good place to have conversations though, so if you are looking for more discussion on the matter, a post to Ubuntu Forums might be better.